# Read MS Excel XML file to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, xml, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an MS Excel XML (2003) file with the following metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
xmlns:c="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
xmlns:x2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml" 
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

I'd like to read it into a pandas dataframe. What's a good way to go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be in XML format? If not then you can read it in using `read_excel`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Canopy python's [pyxll](https://www.enthought.com/products/pyxll), it is advertised as "Python for Excel Solution"

Check it out please and see if it solves your problem.